How to add data validation to the DataGrid's Columns in Avalonia?
I have .Net 8.0 / AvalonuaUI application for editing tables with CommunityToolkit for MVVM.
The configuration of the table is determined at runtime. Therefore, I bind the DataGrid to an object[] collection, then create the Columns at runtime.
I need to validate the input data in each column in a special way.
For example, using minimum and maximum number for numeric parameters (min and max also determined at runtime) or TimeSpan.TryParse() for time parameters.
How can I create custom validators and bind them to the Columns?
At the moment, I am creating Columns in MainWindow.axaml.cs as follows
(I know this is bad for MVVM, but it seems to me the easiest way to create columns dynamically):
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void BuildDataGridColumns(Parameter[] structure)
    {
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < structure.Length; i++)
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(CreateColumn(structure[i], i));
    }

    private DataGridColumn CreateColumn(Parameter parameter, int index)
    {
        switch(parameter.Type.Name)
        {
            case nameof(Boolean):
            {
                return new DataGridCheckBoxColumn() {
                    Header = parameter.Name,
                    Binding = new Binding($"[{index}]"),
                    IsReadOnly = false,
                };
            }

            case nameof(Int32):
            case nameof(Single):
            {
                return new DataGridTextColumn() {
                    Header = parameter.Name,
                    Binding = new Binding($"[{index}]"),
                    IsReadOnly = false
                    //Something like Validator = NumberValidator, etc
                };
            }

            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

MainWindowViewModel.cs
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object?>> Rows { get; set; }
    private MainWindow? _view;

    //Empty cunstructor for preview
    public MainWindowViewModel() : this(null) { }
    public MainWindowViewModel(MainWindow? view)
    {
        _view = view;
        Rows = [[123, 172.32f, true], [321, 3.14f, false], [567, 2.71f, true]];

        Parameter[] structure = new Parameter[] {
            new Parameter("Int", typeof(Int32)),
            new Parameter("Float", typeof(Single)),
            new Parameter("Bool", typeof(Boolean))
        };
        _view?.BuildDataGridColumns(structure);
    }
}

Parameter.cs
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name;
    public Type Type;

    public Parameter(string name, Type type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }
}

Two sided reference in App.axaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    //... generated code ...

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        if(ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            BindingPlugins.DataValidators.RemoveAt(0);

            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(mainWindow);
            desktop.MainWindow = mainWindow;
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
}

